# ExecutorService.invokeAll does NOT support collection of runnable task

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

Wanted to run collection of Runnable task through invokeAll(..) method of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). 
But that's not supported as of now (**supports collection of Callable task only**)

Any specific reason for this? What's the alternative to do something similar.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply transform the runnables into callables:

```
List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
for (Runnable r : runnables) {
    callables.add(toCallable(r));
}
executor.invokeAll(callables);

private Callable<Void> toCallable(final Runnable runnable) {
    return new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            runnable.run();
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: great..this is more of a hack. Java has rich set of API so wondering if there is any specific reason for omitting this method ?

Comment: That's what Java does internal when we provide runnable to ExecutorService

Comment: Java is a rich set of hacks*

Answer (score 41):

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
     public void run() {

     }
};

Callable<Object> c = Executors.callable(task);
```

Just found that, **Executors** provides utility method to convert **Runnable** task into a **Callable** task. That explains why we don't have overloaded **invokeAll** which takes Runnable task as well.