# why does ExecutorService not have invokeAll for Runnable tasks

Tags: runnable, executorservice, callable

I noticed that there are submit methods for both Runnable task and Callable task. Why is there only invokeAll for Callable tasks, but no invokeAll for Runnable tasks. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecutorService.invokeAll does NOT support collection of runnable task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081417/executorservice-invokeall-does-not-support-collection-of-runnable-task)