# Java for loop of threads starting together (almost same time)

Tags: java, multithreading

With this code:

```
 final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                gate.await();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    System.out.println("F1:" + i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestFor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                gate.await();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    System.out.println("F2:" + i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestFor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
```

I am able to start the 2 threads. Now I need more than 2 threads, lets say 50. The only changing parameter in those for loops is `System.out.println("F2:" + i);` as FX where X is the number of the thread.

Is there any way of making those 50 threads inside a for loop ?

Comment: this link will help you > http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Comment: use a countdownlatch, it's easier for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
List<Thread> tList = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    final int id = i;

    tList.add(new Thread() { 
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     gate.await();
                     for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
                         System.out.println("F" + id + ":" + k);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(TestFor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
              }
    });
}
```

To start all of them you simply

```
for(Thread t : tList)
     t.start();
```

If it is really about time and maybe your code for a single Thread increases this will first initialize all of them and start them directly after each other, so you don't need to think about the time you actually need to initialize them.

Comment: local variable "i" is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared finel; neither I can declare an "i" inside a for as final.

Comment: To solve this, inside the for id add: final int test = i; and then use "test" in the system.out.print instead of i

Comment: @Alpha2k added it. Thanks for your reply. Im in a train, so i wasn't able to try to compile it :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean, similar to this?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 50; ++j) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                gate.await();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    System.out.println("F" + j + ":" + i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestFor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `n` threads to start at the same time, you could convert your `Runnable`s into `Callable`s using `Executors.callable()` and then using the `invokeAll()` method on an `ExecutorService`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)

An example is provided at [ExecutorService.invokeAll does NOT support collection of runnable task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081417/executorservice-invokeall-does-not-support-collection-of-runnable-task)