# Understanding Multi-Threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am learning `multithreading` in Java. Problem statement is: Suppose there is a datastruture that can contains million of Integers, now I want to search for a key in this. I want to use 2 threads so that if any one of the thread founds the key, it should set a shared boolean variable as false, and both the thread should stop further processing.

Here is what I am trying:

```
public class Test  implements Runnable{
    private List<Integer> list;
    private Boolean value;
    private int key = 27;

    public Test(List<Integer> list,boolean value) {
        this.list=list;
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (value) {
            if(value){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                if(list.get(i)==key){
                    System.out.println("Found by: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    value = true;
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": "+ list.get(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And main class is:

```
public class MainClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(101);
        for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
            list.add(i);
        }

        Boolean value=false;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Test(list.subList(0, 49),value));
        t1.setName("Thread 1");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Test(list.subList(50, 99),value));
        t2.setName("Thread 2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

**What I am expecting:**

Both threads will run randomly and when any of thread encounters 27, both thread will be interrupted. So, thread 1 should not be able to process all the inputs, similarly thread 2.

**But, what is happening:**

Both threads are completing the loop and thread 2 is always starting after Thread 1 completes.

`Please highlight the mistakes`, I am still learning threading.

My next practice question will be: Access one by one any shared resource

Comment: Why do you use `synchronized`?

Comment: "shared boolean variable" suggests that you may want to use the `static` keyword somewhere relevant...

Comment: @MuratK. Because the `boolean` is the shared resource? is not it correct way??

Comment: @JonK  Doesn't `AtomicBoolean` work here?

Comment: Maybe a `static volatile boolean` would work.

Comment: @px5x2 It would be part of the solution yes - but you still have to share it between the two instances of the `Test` class - and one of the ways to do that is to make the boolean `static` (or you could pass the same reference to the AtomicBoolean through in the ctor)

Comment: @VivekVardhan I had a similar question a while ago, how to start threads at the same time, hope this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535520/java-for-loop-of-threads-starting-together-almost-same-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not obtain a lock on the `found` flag - that will just make sure only one thread can run. Instead make the flag `static` so it is shared and `volatile` so it cannot be cached.

Also, you should check the flag more often.

```
private List<Integer> list;
private int key = 27;
private static volatile boolean found;

public Test(List<Integer> list, boolean value) {
    this.list = list;
    this.found = value;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        // Has the other thread found it?
        if (found) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        if (list.get(i) == key) {
            System.out.println("Found by: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            // I found it!
            found = true;
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + list.get(i));
    }
}
```

BTW: Both of your threads start at `0` and walk up the array - I presume you do this in this code as a demonstration and you either have them work from opposite ends or they walk at random.

Comment: Both the threads are running till the are completing the execution. They are not getting interrupted, loop is getting completed

Comment: if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted\n Exiting...");
                break;
 }

Why I need to add these? why the exceution not stopped when calling `interrupt` method?

Comment: @VivekVardhan - Since `run` cannot throw an interrupt you must check for interrupts yourself. Look at the documentation for `interrupt()`, all it does is set a flag.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrapping your whole block of code under the `synchronized` block under the object `value`. What this means is that, once execution arrives at the synchronized block the first thread will hold the monitor to object `value` and **any subsequent threads will block until the monitor is *released***.

Note how the whole block:

```
synchronized (value){
    if(value){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) == key){
            System.out.println("Found by: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            value = true;
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": "+ list.get(i));
    }
}
```

is wrapped within a synchronized block meaning that only one thread can run that block at once, contrary to your objective.

In this context, I believe you are misunderstanding the principals behind synchronization and "sharing variables". To clarify:

**`static`** - is the variable modifier used to make a variable global across objects (i.e. class variable) such that each object shares the same static variable.

**`volatile`** - is the variable modifier used to make a variable thread-safe. Note that you can still access a variable without this modifier from different threads (this is however dangerous and can lead to race conditions). Threads have no effect on the scope of variables (unless you use a ThreadLocal).

I would just like to add that you can't put `volatile` everywhere and expect code to be thread-safe. I suggest you read [Oracle's guide on synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) for a more in-depth review of how to establish thread-safety.

In your case, I would remove the synchronization block and declare the shared boolean as a:

```
private static volatile Boolean value;
```

Additionally, the task you are trying to perform right now is something a Fork/Join pool is built for. I suggest [reading this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) part of Oracle's java tutorials to see how a Fork/Join pool is used in a divide-and-conquer approach.

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping the main logic of your thread in a synchronized block, execution of the code in that block becomes mutually exclusive. Thread 1 will enter the block, acquiring a lock on "value" and run the entire loop before returning the lock and allowing Thread 2 to run.

If you were to wrap only the checking and setting of the flag "value", then both threads should run the code concurrently.

EDIT: As other people have discussed making "value" a `static volatile boolean` within the Test class, and not using the synchronized block at all, would also work. This is because access to volatile variables occurs as if it were in a synchronized block.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: I guess using `volatile boolean`, I have to make the thread run concurrently. but, how will  I share it?

Comment: Accessing/modifying a volatile variable happens as if it were surrounded by a synchronized block. You have two options:
 1. Keep using a `synchronized` block, but only around where value is modified or accessed.
 2. Make value a `volatile static` member of Test and remove the synchronized block

Answer (score 0):

Make boolean value static so both threads can access and edit the same variable. You then don't need to pass it in. Then as soon as one thread changes it to true, the second thread will also stop since it is using the same value.