# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

i have an array of integers and i want to calculate sum of each integer^2 in multi thread way. i wrote the program and when i run it i get an exception.
The program is as follows:

```
package ir.org.acm.multithreadpower;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Main3 {
    public static volatile int[] a;
    public static int i = 0;
    public static Collection tasks=new ArrayList();
    public static int sum=0;

    static{
        int length=9;
        a=new int[length];
        for(int k=0;k<length;k++)
            a[k]=k;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        new Main3().doJob(executor);
        executor.invokeAll(tasks);
        System.out.println(sum);


    }
    public void doJob(ExecutorService executor) throws Exception{

        for(int m=0;m<(a.length);m++) {
            tasks.add(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    a[i] = a[i] * a[i];
                    i++;
                }
            });
       }

        for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
            sum += k;

        executor.shutdown();

    }
}
```

the program throws a run-time exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ir.org.acm.multithreadpower.Main3$2 cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Callable
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(AbstractExecutorService.java:235)
    at ir.org.acm.multithreadpower.Main3.main(Main3.java:35)
```

i googled this issue but could not figure out this problem
thanks for your help.

regards,

Comment: `invokeAll() ` method does not support `Runnable`. You should transform your `Runnable` to `Callable`. Take a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081417/executorservice-invokeall-does-not-support-collection-of-runnable-task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081417/executorservice-invokeall-does-not-support-collection-of-runnable-task)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
public static Collection tasks=new ArrayList();
```

This is a [rawtype](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), which means the compiler cannot ensure safety when using this `Collection`.

How, lets look at [`Executor.invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-), the signature is:

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
```

So your `Collection` needs to contain `Callable<T>` (where `T` doesn't matter).

Now, lets look at your code:

```
public void doJob(ExecutorService executor) throws Exception {
    for(int m=0;m<(a.length);m++) {
        tasks.add(new Runnable() {
                    //^ here
```

So you are adding `Runnable`. Obviously `Runnable` **is not** `Callable`.

### TL;DR:

Change:

```
public static Collection tasks = new ArrayList();
```

to:

```
public static Collection<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

then you'll have many compiler errors to fix.

---

When you compiled this code, you would have gotten a warning such as:

```
[WARNING] ...App.java:[17,27] unchecked method invocation: method invokeAll in interface java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService is applied to given types
  required: java.util.Collection<? extends java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>>
  found: java.util.Collection
[WARNING] ...App.java:[17,28] unchecked conversion
  required: java.util.Collection<? extends java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>>
  found:    java.util.Collection
```

**don't ignore compiler warnings.**

Answer (score 0):

You should also move  *executor.shutdown();* from the method *doJob* to after *executor.invokeAll(tasks);*