# Java Thread Pool - Execute Threads Later

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

How do I store my runnable workers so I can call them later?

```
public class VirusPool {

    public ExecutorService executor;
    public ArrayList<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public VirusPool(LifeProcessor lp, boolean[][] gameBoard, 
        ArrayList<Point> point, ReentrantLock lock, ArrayList<Point> survivingCells){
        int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);  
        for (int k = 0; k < threads; k++){  
            Runnable worker = new VirusThread(lp,gameBoard,point,lock,survivingCells,k+1,8);
            tasks.add(worker);
        }              
    }

    public void start(){
        for (Runnable task : tasks){
            executor.execute(task);
        }
        executor.shutdown();  
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {   }  
    }}
```

I'm looking at executor.invokeAll but not sure how to implement it with my current code.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: a class called VirusPool doesn't sound like a class I'd personally like to help you get working

Comment: Haha, I'm implementing the Game of Life, just thought would be a funny name :p

Comment: invokeAll doesn't support collection of Runnable tasks. checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081417/executorservice-invokeall-does-not-support-collection-of-runnable-task

Comment: @PradeepSingh this will work tyvm <3

Comment: If you want to use invokeAll then use Callable tasks. Which also help in returning some value. if you don't need a return value then also you can use a Callable. But the good practice is use callable when you need to have returned some values. We get returned value through the help of Future object return by Callable tasks submit by executor.